# How can I add top drawer and bottom navigation in android activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, bottomnavigationview

How to add top drawer and bottom tab navigation in whole application?
I tried to combine 2 activity in android studio and its causing design issue. Its not working

Comment: We don't have any way to know what kind of design issues you are getting. Could you explain better with some relevant code and design screenshot may be.

Answer (score 0):

For the bottom navigation 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView

For Top drawer exaplain a little what exactly you want

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this throughout your whole **`Project`** in this way.

Use this as an `activity_main.xml` like as your `MainActivity.java` class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_180"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/top_lay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/userimageLay"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                    <com.team.helperclasses.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/userimage"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_100"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_100"
                        android:src="@mipmap/side_menu_profile_"
                        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"
                        app:civ_border_overlay="true"
                        app:civ_border_width="1dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/editProfile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/top_lay"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp_5"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_5">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/editProfileText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/editProfileImage"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_8"
                    android:text="@string/editProfile"
                    android:textColor="@color/dull_black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_18" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/editProfileImage"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_45"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_45"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/side_menu_profile" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/editProfiledivider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editProfile"
                android:background="@color/light_black" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/sharedWall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editProfile"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp_5"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_5">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sharedWallText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/shareWallImage"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_8"
                    android:text="@string/sharedWall"
                    android:textColor="@color/dull_black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_18" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/shareWallImage"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_45"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_45"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/wall" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/shareWallDivider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sharedWall"
                android:background="@color/light_black" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/changeLang"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/shareWallDivider"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp_5"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_5">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/changeLangText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/changeLangImage"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_8"
                    android:text="@string/changeLanguage"
                    android:textColor="@color/dull_black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_18" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/changeLangImage"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_45"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_45"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/language" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/changeLangdivider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/changeLang"
                android:background="@color/light_black" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/logout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/changeLangdivider"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp_5"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_5">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/logoutText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/logoutImage"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_8"
                    android:text="@string/logout"
                    android:textColor="@color/dull_black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_18" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/logoutImage"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_45"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_45"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/log_out" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

& the Layout `app_bar_home.xml` looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.team.activities.Home">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:title="@string/app_name"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/search"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_22" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/searchHome"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/notificationLay"
                    android:src="@mipmap/search" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/notificationLay"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_5">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/notification"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="@dimen/dp_5"
                        android:src="@mipmap/notification" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/notify"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/notification"
                        android:padding="@dimen/dp_5"
                        android:src="@drawable/counter_bg" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

& `content_home.xml` in which you can define the things as per your requirement in the application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.team.activities.Home"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_space"
        android:name="com.presence.fragments.HomeFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_lay" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_lay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_50"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_create"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_create"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/text_create"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/create" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_create"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/create"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp_10" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_received"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_received"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/text_received"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/recived" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_received"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/received"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp_10" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_sent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_sent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/text_sent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/sent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_sent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/sent"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp_10" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_website"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_website"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/text_travel"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/web" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_travel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/booking"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp_10" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Try this hope it helps you.